# How to set type to generic?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this generic in seald class:

```
sealed class ResponseResult {
    class Success<T>(val data: T, val city: String) : ResponseResult()
}
```

I'm setting my Response<Weather> body in this Success class with succesful call in my ViewModel:

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
   response.body().let {
   _screenState.postValue(ResponseResult.Success(it, cityName))
}
```

but when i'm trying to get fields from my Weather array (which is Response type of) in fragment i can't get them because my type is Any.

```
viewModel.screenState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            when (it) {
                is ResponseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    setSuccessResult()
                    it.data.
                }
```

How can i make my generic understand that this is type of "Weather"?

Comment: Your `ResponseResult` needs to have a generic argument as well

Comment: in sealed class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
sealed class ResponseResult<T> {
    class Success<T>(val data: T, val city: String) : ResponseResult<T>()
}
```

In your view model

```
val _screenState = MutableLiveData<ResponseResult<Weather>>()
```

In your fragment

```
viewModel.screenState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        when (it) {
            is ResponseResult.Success -> {
                setSuccessResult()
                val data: Weather = it.data
                //use data the way you want
            }
}
```

Comment: How should i change my second code part? It saying "Weather? type found"

Comment: I still can't get my fields from Weather in fragment :(

Comment: oh i see. there is just no need for <*> in succes. thank you!